# Speed up sending multiple emails through smtp server using System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, email, smtp

I am quite a newbie in C# but I have learnt a lot from VB.Net about programming in .Net for windows.

I have just made a simple SMTP client which sends emails from the program. It is a console application and can only send one email through the server at a time. This is very slow and I need to send multiple emails through my client at the *same time*.

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: use asynchronous mechanism..

Comment: Maybe you didn't read but I said im pretty nooby at c# so I have no idea how to do that... but thx anyway

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on [Multithreading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Your welcome. Nowadays it's recommended to use [System.Threading.Tasks.Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of "manually" creating each individual thread. [Here's](http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/a/multi-threading-using-task-parallel-library.htm) an example of how to use it (at end of arcticle).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply use multiple threads (multiple processes).

In C# you can do this with a Task.

```
new Task(delegate { 
    smtpClient.send(myMessage); 
}).Start();
```

Just wrap your `send` command in this object and it will be send Asynchronously.

Be careful if this is wrapped in a loop it will start a new process for each mail.

if you need to send large amounts of mails at the same time I suggest you use a `ThreadPool`. It lets you control how many concurent threads you'd like to have at the same time.