# Sending multiple Emails using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I have a `List<EMailData>` which contains 'n' number of emails, content and attachment.
I used loop for list to send email and its taking time. 
Is there a way by which it sends multiple emails in less time?

class `EMailData` has EmailID, EMailContent and Attachment as properties

```
    private void SendEmail() {
        for(int i=0; i<objlstEmailData.Count; i++) {
            List<System.Net.Mail.Attachment> lstAttachment = new List<System.Net.Mail.Attachment>();
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment att = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(new System.IO.MemoryStream(objlstEmailData[i].EmailAttachment), "Invoice.pdf");
            lstAttachment.Add(att);
            DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendEmail(fromEmail, fromEmail, objlstEmailData[i].EmailId, "Inovice - XXX", objlstEmailData[i].EmailData, lstAttachment);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: are you sending the exact same email to the group of users, or are you sending emails with data unique to each specific user? If you are sending the exact same email, why not just put all their email addresses into the BCC field and just send the one email?

Comment: can you define "a long time"? show your code.

Comment: Also, speeding this up increases the likelihood of triggering spamfilters. You may have other problems than you now think.

Comment: read the following links: http://serverfault.com/questions/133526/sending-lots-of-mails-using-smtpclient-c-takes-very-long-after-a-while http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747498/speed-up-sending-multiple-emails-through-smtp-server-using-system-net-mail

Comment: I have updated the question with my current code